# Delete a record from database using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The Remove.java is the servlet and the index.jsp is the jsp file. I am trying to delete the file using email,since it is unique.

Remove.java

```
package servletPool;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Remove")
public class Remove extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String uEmail = request.getParameter("email");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "root";
        String query = "delete from user_details where email=?";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://locahost:3306/dbname", user, pass);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from user_details where email=?");
        ps.setString(1, uEmail);

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();

        if(i > 0) {
            out.println("User successfully removed...");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

and here is the index.jsp file from which the record will be deleted.

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page.</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>


           <div style="padding : 10px;">
            <center>

                <form action="Remove.servlet" method="get">
                <h5>If you  want to remove users,</h5>
                <input type="email" placeHolder="User's Email" name="email"/>
                <input type="button" value="Click" name="remove"/>
                </form>

            </center>
        </div>

    </center>

    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: sorry for error but there is method="post", in the index.jsp.

Comment: Could you please verify the form action?  Try this: action="/Remove"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: First of always after try{...} use finally{ and con.close();}

Comment: Now please try to cut your problem into pieces and try to find out where the problem is.For example does your query works as a query in your sql management??Do you take any errors or simply you dont manage to see this record deleted??

Comment: ps.close(); also needed.

Comment: your control is reached in servlet or not check.I think your control is not reached in servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from:

```
<form action="Remove.servlet" method="get">
```

to:

```
<form action="Remove" method="post">
```

and from:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" name="remove"/>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Click" name="remove"/>
```

In addition, line 26 (`</center>`) in index.jsp and line 29 (`String query = "delete from user_details where email=?";`) in Remove.java should be removed because they are unnecessary.